# Get index from table (the tr has no ID)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic, html-table

I'm dynamically creating and appending into a table, a `<tr>` and a `<td>` with the following code:

```
$("#table1").append(
        '<tr>'+
        '<td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="pass.data.carregar(this.parentNode.rowIndex-2);">'+$("#DRVR_NAME").val()+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>');
```

It's Ok so far: I can load the Td data into another fields that I want and there's no problem on creating it.

But beyond creating it I must allow the user to remove the `<td>` dynamically, but as you can see, there's no ID to look for. What's the better way to allow the user to remove the `<td>` ?

Im trying the following code:

```
$("#table1>tbody>td>tr."+teste+"").remove();
```

But no success! The test variable is a number that I automatically define for the register.

Any help?

Comment: Can't you add an id attribute to what you're appending? Unless there's some unique identifier or it always stays in the same order, there isn't any way to target a specific element. If you always know it will be the first cell in a row, though, you could use .index() or .eq()

Comment: TR comes before TD by the way, that could be your problem. If you have more than once table cell you will run into problems with that code though.

Comment: @MarcySutton Hi Marcy, unfortunately I can't add an Id to the append because they'll receive another counter, trasfered by another function.
I have a counter here, if I could select the TR by using that selector it would be nice, but i just dont know how to do that, i tried many ways but no success. **Let's assume that we have a counter called "USERID", how should I do to get the desired TR by using that value?**

Comment: How is the delete being triggered from the user?

Comment: **@kingjiv** The user selects the item from the list, then its loaded into the needed fields, and then the user has the option to delete it.

**@MarcySutton** Marcy, i must count the TDs. I followed your tip, about the TR comming before the TD, that was probably a typo mistake, but still cant get it to work. My counter is actually a hidden filed, and it's value changes according to the selected TD in the "users list" (the table).

Comment: @user727901 Does it work if you take out ">tbody" in your remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `test` is the 0-based index of the row you want to remove...

```
$("#table1>tbody>tr:eq("+test+")").remove();
```

Comment: Brandom, it works but it start deleting from zero, that is a text! Can i start it at n. 2?

Comment: yeah sure, just use `(test+2)` instead of `test` above.

Comment: Brandon, it worked perfectly!! Thanks for helping, i couldn't imagine that is was so simple... the simplest solutions are the hardest to find!! Thanks a alot again! :)

Comment: If Brandon solved the problem, you should mark his answer as "Accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left of his answer. =)

Comment: @Armando Freire - I'm glad it worked.  You were very close to the solution yourself and just needed a nudge.

Answer (score 0):

Set a unique id attribute when you dynamically create each cell.

```
<tr id="uniqueID"><td>Cell Content</td></tr>
```

Then use simple jquery to remove the row by id.

```
$('#uniqueID').remove();
```

Comment: I tryed that but i cant get it to work, because I have an array that must be updated everytime the user add/remove an element.
Actualy it works, but if i remove the first element of the table, i cant access the anothers.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a little x next to each driver name that will delete that td by changing your code a bit:

```
$("#table1").append('<tr>'+'<td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="pass.data.carregar(this.parentNode.rowIndex-2);">'+$("#DRVR_NAME").val()+'<span onclick="$(this.parentNode).remove()">x</span></td>'+'</tr>');
```

Or you could add another function to the click handler that you are binding to each `<td>` that will display a message in a predefined `<div>` asking the user if s/he wants to delete that element:

```
$("#table1").append('<tr>'+'<td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="pass.data.carregar(this.parentNode.rowIndex-2);askDelete(this);">'+$("#DRVR_NAME").val()+'</td>'+'</tr>');
```

and then define a message area (id = 'messageArea') somewhere in your HTML and the following function in your code:

```
askDelete(el){
    var MA=$('#messageArea');
    MA.empty();
    MA.html('Do you want to delete ' + el.innerHTML + '?<br>').append('<span id="confirmDelete">delete</span>&nbsp;<span id="cancelDelete">cancel</span>')
    MA.find('#confirmDelete').click(function(){$(el).remove();});
    MA.find('#cancelDelete').click(function(){MA.empty();})
}
```

then style your delete and cancel buttons as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Your remove code assumes there is a class on the TD. You'll have to target it with :eq() by referencing the value in your hidden field. If the value in the hidden field is a number (the index of the td the user selected = your counter), you could try something like this:

```
var hiddenFieldValue = $('input.hiddenFieldClassName').val();

$("#table1>tbody>tr>td:eq("+hiddenFieldValue+")").remove();
```